# TOP-10 самых повторяющихся слов

Tags: php

Привет всем! Нужно составить TOP-10 самых повторяющихся слов (больше 3-х букв) из файла input.txt и сделать после сортировки поместить в файл outbox.txt.

В файле input.txt указываются слова построчно.

Начал делать, но сделать сортировку не получается.

Вот мое начало:

```
$f_arr = file( "input.txt" );

$new = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($f_arr); $i++)
{
    if(strlen($f_arr[$i])-2 > 3)
    {
        $arr[$new] = $f_arr[$i];
        $new = $new +1;
    }
}

//сортировка

foreach($arr as $a)
{
    echo $a . '<br />';
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(strlen($f_arr[$i])-2 > 3)
{
    $arr[$f_arr[$i]] = ($arr[$f_arr[$i]] > 0) ? $arr[$f_arr[$i]]+1 : 1;
}
```

потом сортировку по значению.

мб даже вот так:

```
if(strlen($f_arr[$i])-2 > 3)
{
    $arr[$f_arr[$i]]++;
}
```

Comment: Немного не понятно, как это работает. Если Вам не сложно, могли бы Вы соединить с моим кодом, ибо я заблудился. =)

Comment: По сути в ассоциативный массив записывается ключ - слово, а значение у ключа прибавляется на 1. Дальше вы сортируете по убыванию по значению и через foreach выводите данные. Как-то так. Код давайте сами подцепляйте, там crtl+c ctrl+v только использовать.